# GROUP BY multiple conditions at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a tables like this:

Users

```
+----+----------+-------------+                           
| id | name     | other_stuff |                           
+----+----------+-------------+                           
|  1 | John Doe |           x |                           
|  2 | Jane Doe |           y |                           
|  3 | Burt Olm |           z |                           
+----+----------+-------------+
```

Places

```
+----+------------+-------------+                         
| id | name       | other_stuff |                         
+----+------------+-------------+                         
|  1 | Building A |           x |                         
|  2 | Building B |           y |                         
+----+------------+-------------+
```

Subjects

```
+----+------------+-------------+                         
| id | name       | other_stuff |                         
+----+------------+-------------+                         
|  1 |       Math |           x |                         
|  2 |    English |           y |                         
+----+------------+-------------+
```

And a joining table:

PastLectures = lectures that took place

```
+----+-----------+----------+------------+---------+------------+
| id | id_users  | id_place | id_subjects| length  | date       |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+---------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 |          1 |      60 | 2015-10-25 |
|  2 |         1 |        1 |          1 |     120 | 2015-11-06 |
|  3 |         2 |        2 |          2 |     120 | 2015-11-04 |
|  4 |         2 |        2 |          1 |      60 | 2015-11-10 |
|  5 |         1 |        2 |          1 |      60 | 2015-11-10 |
|  6 |         2 |        2 |          1 |      40 | 2015-11-15 |
|  7 |         1 |        2 |          2 |      30 | 2015-11-15 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+---------+------------+
```

I would like to display SUM of all lessons for **each user** for given month. The SUM should by grouped by each **Places** and **Subjects**.

The result in final PHP output should look like this:

```
November 2015                                             
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Users.name | Places.name | Subjects.name | sum(length) |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
|   Burt Olm |           - |             - |           - |
|   Jane Doe |  Building B |          Math |         100 |
|          = |           = |       English |         120 |
|   John Doe |  Building A |          Math |         120 |
|          = |  Building B |          Math |          60 |
|          = |           = |       English |          30 |
+------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

I have tried creating the full output in pure SQL query using multiple GROUP BY ([Group by - multiple conditions - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472330/group-by-multiple-conditions-mysql)), but when I do **GROUP BY User.id,Places.id** it shows each user only once (3 results) no matter the other GROUP BY conditions.

SQL:

```
SELECT PastLectures.id_users,Users.name AS user,Places.name AS places,Subjects.name AS subjects
  FROM PastLectures
  LEFT JOIN Users ON PastLectures.id_users = Users.id
  LEFT JOIN Places ON PastLectures.id_Places = Places.id
  LEFT JOIN Subjects ON PastLectures.id_Subjects = Subjects.id
  WHERE date >= \''.$monthStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'\' AND date <= \''.$monthEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'\'
  GROUP BY Users.id,Places.id
  ORDER BY Users.name,Places.name,Subjects.name
```

But I don't mind if part of the solution is done in PHP, I just don't know what to do next.

**EDIT:**

I also have a table Timetable, that stores **who** regularly teaches **what** and **where**. It stores only used combinations of the tables (each valid combination once).

```
Timetable = lectures that regularly take place
+----+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+
| id | id_users  | id_place | id_subjects| other_stuff |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 |          1 |           x |
|  2 |         1 |        2 |          1 |           y |
|  3 |         1 |        2 |          2 |           z |
|  4 |         2 |        2 |          1 |           a |
|  5 |         2 |        2 |          2 |           b |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to add only users with combinations that have a row in this table?

In this case it would mean omitting **Burt Olm** (no id=3 in Timetable). But if Burt has a Timetable entry and still no PastLectures entry, he would show here as in sample result (he should have had a lecture that month, because he is in Timetable, but no lectures took place).

Based on @Barmar's solution I updated the final SQL by making Timetable a primary table and adding one more `LEFT JOIN` to suffice those needs.

Final SQL:

```
SELECT Users.name AS user,Places.name AS places,Subjects.name AS subjects, SUM(PastLectures.length)
  FROM Timetable
  LEFT JOIN PastLectures ON PastLectures.id_users = Timetable.id_users AND PastLectures.id_place = Timetable.id_place AND PastLectures.id_subjects = Timetable.id_subjects
    AND date BETWEEN '2015-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-30 23:59:59'
  LEFT JOIN Places ON Timetable.id_Place = Places.id
  LEFT JOIN Subjects ON Timetable.id_Subjects = Subjects.id
  LEFT JOIN Users ON Timetable.id_users = Users.id
  GROUP BY Timetable.id,Timetable.id_users,Timetable.id_Place,Timetable.id_Subjects
  ORDER BY Users.name,Places.name,Subjects.name
```

Comment: Where is `SUM(length)` in the query?

Comment: `datum` doesn't appear to be a field in any of the tables. Also, Users should probably be the leftmost table, and the date condition(s) moved to an ON clause, if you want Burt in the tesults.

Comment: @Uueerdo I guess that's a typo for `date`. Better (IMHO) to use `BETWEEN` instead of two conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `Subjects.id` in the `GROUP BY`, so you get a separate result for each subject.

Also, you shouldn't use columns in tables that are joined with `LEFT JOIN` in the `GROUP BY` column. If you do that, all the non-matching rows will be grouped together, because they all have `NULL` in that column. Use the columns in the main table.

```
GROUP BY PastLectures.id_users, PastLectures.id_Place, PastLectures.id_Subjects
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fa2d/3)

Note that there's no row for Burt Olm in the demo output, because all his rows are filtered out by the `WHERE` clause. If you want all users to be shown, you should make `Users` the main table, not `PastLectures`. And the `date` criteria needs to be moved into the `ON` clause when joining with `PastLectures`.

```
SELECT Users.name AS user,Places.name AS places,Subjects.name AS subjects, SUM(length)
  FROM Users
  LEFT JOIN PastLectures ON PastLectures.id_users = Users.id 
    AND date BETWEEN '2015-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-11-30 23:59:59'
  LEFT JOIN Places ON PastLectures.id_Place = Places.id
  LEFT JOIN Subjects ON PastLectures.id_Subjects = Subjects.id
  GROUP BY Users.id, PastLectures.id_Place, PastLectures.id_Subjects
  ORDER BY Users.name,Places.name,Subjects.name
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fa2d/5)

Comment: Perfect! Can you please also look at the Edit?

Comment: The join between `Timetable` and `PastLectures` should match all the `id_XXX` columns.

Comment: Please don't ask such a different question as an edit. It should be a new question. You can link back to this question to help clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

According to standard SQL, you should GROUP BY all the fields you select, except for the aggregated fields (like sum). Althought MySql allows to do otherwise, when it can be done adhering to the standards, it is better to do so (who knows when you need to port your code to another database engine). So write your SQL like this:

```
  SELECT    PastLectures.id_users,
            Users.name AS user,
            Places.name AS places,
            Subjects.name AS subjects,
            Sum(length)
  FROM      PastLectures
  LEFT JOIN Users       ON PastLectures.id_users = Users.id
  LEFT JOIN Places      ON PastLectures.id_Places = Places.id
  LEFT JOIN Subjects    ON PastLectures.id_Subjects = Subjects.id
  WHERE     date BETWEEN \''.$monthStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'\'
                 AND     \''.$monthEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'\'
  GROUP BY  PastLectures.id_users,
            Users.name,
            Places.name,
            Subjects.name
  ORDER BY  Users.name,
            Places.name,
            Subjects.name
```

Comment: Not required by MySQL, and it is better to group by id's as @Barmar suggested in case two users have the same name.

Comment: MySQL doesn't require this grouping, unless you enable the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

Comment: I know that MySql allows non-standard SQL, but when it is not needed, it is better to stick with the standard, who knows when you need to port your code to another engine...

Comment: But you're running into another problem. You're grouping by columns in a `LEFT JOIN` table, and they may be `NULL` for rows with no match.

Comment: I believe that is what the OP wanted: to have groups with NULL. At least that is what I see in the example output.

Comment: But it will combine all the rows where the columns are null into a single group.

Comment: And that I think is just fine. You don't have any information in the result that could show what the different sub-groups would be, unless you would add the IDs, but then you would -- in standard SQL -- also group by those.

Comment: And, to have the effect you hint at, the OP's `group by` clause will not help, since `Places.id` will also be NULL in such cases. It would have to be `PastLectures.id_places` to get that effect. Same for the other fields.